# React router v6 testing library navigate relative fails

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, testing-library, navigatetourl

In my application i use relative navigation with react router v6 (we are currently migrating) and it works fine.

When i try to do some tests using Jest and testing-library the relative navigation fails and always resolve with the pathname '/'.

I use this wrapper to render my component under test to add it a Router.

```
const WrapTestComponentInRouter = (TestComponent, initialRoute = '/', history =['/']) => {
  function WrappedComponent(props) {
    return (
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={history}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={initialRoute} element={<TestComponent {...props} />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Location />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  }

  return WrappedComponent;
};

function ComponentToTest() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
  const path = useResolvedPath('..');
  console.log(path);
  return <button onClick={() => navigate('..')}>navigate</div>;
}
```

I use the hook useResolvedPath to compute the navigation result and log it. In my application the relative path computed is correct but in my test it is always equals to '/' whatever the current location is.

Does someone has encounter and solved this problem?

EDIT

Ok, i understand what is the problem. The useResolvedPath is using the routingContext to compute the relative route so if we use '..' it pop to the previous route in the route tree.

With that, if i want to test my navigation i need to reproduce my route tree. Another solution is to use the real relative path by using the method resolvePath('..', location)

The resolvePath compute relative path from a path

```
resolvePath('..', '/user/project') ---> '/user'
```

the navigate function also use the RoutingContext so if i want to do a relative from the current path i have to do

```
const location = useLocation();
navigate(resolvePath('..', location.pathname));
```

Comment: in 6.0 they bugfixed useResolvedPath behaviour. Maybe this is related?
Resolution of <Link to="."> and useResolvedPath(".") values are fixed in splat routes. Previously these resolved relative to the parent route's path. They now resolve relative to the path of the route that rendered them.

Comment: i'm on the latest version 6.2.2 so it is not related to that bug i think

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test here? I see you've a test component, and routes, and a router... seems hardly a "unit test".

Comment: it is not the full test just an example, i would like to test the routing but i made a mistake. The relative .. is not about the location but about all the sub routes.

Comment: Don't test code you don't own, assume the 3rd-party router code has been tested and works. Test *your* code.

Comment: @DrewReese i'm not testing the library, i asked this question because we are migrating fromv5 to v6 and some tests on our application fails. Now that i have understood how it worksit s ok.

Comment: I run into the same problem, have to switch to absolute path for all navigate() calls so as to get the test pass, eg, navigate(`./../modules`) lead to wrong path only in test environment, have to change to navigate(`/regions/12345/entities/54321/modules`), not cool

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, the way I solved it was to write the whole app routing hierarchy, and mount the wanted component only.
for example:

```
<MemoryRouter
     initialEntries={['/1/page1/2/3']}>
     <Routes>
         <Route path="/:param1">
             <Route path="page1/*"
                  element={<MyComponent />}>
                  <Route path=":param2/*">
                      <Route path=":param3" />
                  </Route>
             </Route>
        </Route>
   </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>
```